# ¿Como mostrar una lista circular de manera invertida?

Tags: java, lista

Hola estimados programadores, soy un simple novato en java y tengo una duda, estoy trabajando con una lista circular que guarde caracteres y los imprima de orden ascendente y descendente por ejemplo:
me debo de imprimir la forma original: a->b->c->d->e y también me la debe de imprimir de la siguiente manera: e->d->c->b->a.

Tengo mi clase Nodo la cual es la siguiente:

```
public class Nodo {
public char dato;
Nodo siguiente;
public Nodo(char d){
    dato=d;
    siguiente=this;//apunta a el mismo

}
```

Tengo una clase llamada métodos en la cual tengo mi método de Inserción:

```
  public Metodos Insert(char caracter) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(caracter);
    if (raiz != null) {//si es diferente ya hay un nodo
        nuevo.siguiente = raiz.siguiente;
        raiz.siguiente = nuevo;
    }
    raiz = nuevo;
    return this;
}
```

Mi método Mostrar, este lo muestra en la forma original:

```
public void Mostrar() {
    Nodo aux = raiz.siguiente;
    String valor = "";
    do {
        valor = valor + "[" + aux.dato + "]->";
        aux=aux.siguiente;
    } while (aux != raiz.siguiente);
    System.out.println(valor);
}
```

Necesito crear otro método para que lo imprima de la segunda manera y no puedo hacerlo, la verdad es que ya no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, espero me puedan asesorar, de antemano muchas gracias!!!